# EXC_BREAKPOINT randomly using NSOutputStream

Tags: ios, nsstream, nsoutputstream

I'm writing an app which uses NSOutputStream. I init connection like this:

```
delegate = self;
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)url,port, &readStream, &writeStream);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:delegate];
[outputStream setDelegate:delegate];

loop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:loop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:loop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1 forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
[outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1 forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];



[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL
                  forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
[outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL
                   forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                          kCFNull,kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                          nil];

CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty((CFWriteStreamRef)outputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)settings);

[outputStream open];
[inputStream open];

[self sendVersionOrWait];
[loop run];
```

and then do some action depends on NSStreamDelegate methods. Closing conection is done by:

```
 [inputStream close];
[outputStream close];
[inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream setDelegate:nil];
[outputStream setDelegate:nil];

inputStream = nil;
outputStream = nil;
```

Sometimes (it is randomly) I get EXC_BREAKPOINT and the app crashes. This is part of crash log:

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Triggered by Thread:  5

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Thread 5 Crashed:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x22767e22 CFHash + 130

1   CoreFoundation                  0x22768d70 CFBasicHashGetCountOfKey + 1152

2   CoreFoundation                  0x227688aa CFSetContainsValue + 98

3   CoreFoundation                  0x2279ca5a CFRunLoopRemoveSource + 226

4   CFNetwork                       0x22343eca SocketStream::write(__CFWriteStream*, unsigned char const*, long, CFStreamError*) + 426

5   CFNetwork                       0x223480c2 
WriteStreamCallbacks::_write(__CFWriteStream*, unsigned char const*, long, CFStreamError*, void*) + 34

6   CoreFoundation                  0x2278d7ec CFWriteStreamWrite + 356

7   App                             0x000a0190 -[AppMenuViewController sendVersion] (AppMenuViewController.m:763)

8   App                             0x000a0c68 -[AppMenuViewController sendVersionOrWait] (AppMenuViewController.m:832)

9   Foundation                      0x235655e4 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 464

10  CoreFoundation                  0x22828734 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 12

11  CoreFoundation                  0x228282b4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 652

12  CoreFoundation                  0x2282651e __CFRunLoopRun + 1414

13  CoreFoundation                  0x22773dac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472

14  CoreFoundation                  0x22773bbe CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102

15  Foundation                      0x234ab16c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 260

16  Foundation                      0x234f95e0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76

17  App                             0x0009feaa -[AppMenuViewController initConnection:withPort:] (AppMenuViewController.m:749)

18  App                             0x000a1642 -[AppMenuViewController stream:handleEvent:] (AppMenuViewController.m:952)

19  CoreFoundation                  0x227d9b94 _signalEventSync + 144

20  CoreFoundation                  0x227e3ef2 _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 198

21  CoreFoundation                  0x227d981e _CFStreamSignalEvent + 322

22  CFNetwork                       0x222b7bd4 SocketStream::dispatchSignalFromSocketCallbackUnlocked(SocketStreamSignalHolder*) + 36

23  CFNetwork                       0x222b78be SocketStream::socketCallback(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*) + 146

24  CFNetwork                       0x222b77f2 SocketStream::_SocketCallBack_stream(__CFSocket*, unsigned long, __CFData const*, void const*, void*) + 54

25  CoreFoundation                  0x2282b0bc __CFSocketPerformV0 + 552

26  CoreFoundation                  0x22828804 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 12

27  CoreFoundation                  0x22827c16 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218

28  CoreFoundation                  0x22826294 __CFRunLoopRun + 764

29  CoreFoundation                  0x22773dac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472

30  CoreFoundation                  0x22773bbe CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102

31  Foundation                      0x234ab16c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 260

32  Foundation                      0x234f95e0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76

33  App                             0x0009feaa -[AppMenuViewController initConnection:withPort:] (AppMenuViewController.m:749)

34  App                             0x0009b664 __58-[AppMenuViewController alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]_block_invoke (AppMenuViewController.m:385)

35  libdispatch.dylib               0x30521610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8

36  libdispatch.dylib               0x3052d350 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 816

37  libdispatch.dylib               0x3052e27a _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102

38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3069ee22 _pthread_wqthread + 666

39  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3069eb74 start_wqthread + 4

**I suppose it can be caused by network problems because it appears when my WIFI router doesn't have Internet connection. But I'm not sure and I don't know how to remove this error. Please, help :)**

Comment: Remove the breakpoints if you have put any, then check

Comment: I did this but nothing has changed

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but did you ever find the cause of this problem? I am seeing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is related to threading.
Try doing a dispatch to main thread to make sure this is all done on the main thread, and see if that magically cures the problem. If so, you know where to look....